# MDADM Array help

Tags: mdadm

I was running ubuntu 11.04 and my boot drive has become corrupt.  This has stopped me from accessing my raid5 array.

The array was set up in MDADM and called MD0 i think. Can I install ubuntu 11.04 on a new os drive and pull back my array? If so what would I need to do?

Are there any important config files on the old drive?  I think part of the VAR directory is unreadable.

Comment: Can you get access to your original /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf file?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little shaky on doing this, and I can't guarantee that it won't destroy anything. I did go through the same situation and managed to get mine back. I don't remember exactly what I did as it was quite some ago. I think once I had my .conf file restored, I could use '`mdadm --assemble --scan`', and it this doesn't work, you can re-assemble the drive (assuming you know the partitions) using something similar to '`mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1`' where md0 is your raid partition and sdb1 and sdb2 are the component partitions.

Comment: The array is made of 4 WD10EARS 1 TB drives.  Its a 3TB raid 5 array.  Im not sure of the order on the drives, is there anyway to find this out, or can I assemble the array with it automatically recognising the order.  The drives are single partitions made using MDADM so things like gparted see them as unformatted.

Comment: I think you should be safe trying the --scan. I had a question above asking if you can get access to the original mdadm.conf file  (/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf). I think this will have useful information in it if you can still access it.

Comment: Hh, Ive installed a new os drive, and a fresh copy of ubuntu 11.04.  I have installed MDADM and run the MDADM -assemble --scan command, nand it comes back with /dev/md0 assembled from 2 drives - not enough to start the array .... the array had 4 drives using 3, so why isnt it picking them up?   I really dont want to loose the data on it.

Comment: Not sure ... you could try assembling manually (mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sda1 ... etc, adding all 4 parts).

Comment: Tried that, getting the msg:  mdadm: /dev/md0 assembled from 2 drives - not enough to start the array - msg

Comment: Can you add all 4 partitions? ... I assume you know which devices they are.

Comment: I have a printout from mdadm --detail /dev/md0 taht might make more sense.  Do you have a generic email address that I can post it to?  It basically says that drives 1 & 3 have been removed from the array.  Even though they are present and it sees them.

Comment: You can use PasteBin for that, although I'm not sure I can help any further.